# Remapping Alt-rightcursor in Bash/Readline + PuTTY

Tags: bash, putty, readline

I want to remap <kbd>Alt-B</kbd> (`backward-word`) in Bash (accessed over SSH/PuTTY). I managed to remap <kbd>Alt-F</kbd> (`forward-word`) in `.inputrc`:

```
set editing-mode vi

"^[": backward-word
"^[": forward-word
```

(obviously `^[` character is entered using <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd> and then key combination like <kbd>Alt-rightcursor</kbd>)

<kbd>Alt-rightcursor</kbd> works. But <kbd>Alt-leftcursor</kbd> does not move one word back.

What's the reason and how can I fix this?

Comment: Where did the rest of those binding strings go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried escape, right? escape, left

AutoHotKey can help

```
; if PuTTY
#IfWinActive, ahk_class PuTTY
  ^V::Send +{Insert}
  !Left::Send {Escape Down}{Left}{Escape Up}
  !Right::Send {Escape Down}{Right}{Escape Up}
  ^Delete::Send ^k
  ^Backspace::Send ^u
  !Backspace::Send ^w
  !Delete::Send !d
  ^w::RunWait C:\__win\dev\projects\Hotkeys\Hotkeys\bin\x64\Release\Hotkeys.exe G18
#IfWinActive
```

(The last shortcut uses C# to close window)

You also have to set PuTTY Terminal-type string to `linux` in Connection->Data